# Show that any non-trivial solution has at most 1 zero in R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Show that any non-trivial solution of the differential equation $y''+(1/4)(2-x^2)y=0$ has at most $1$ zero in $\mathbb R$.

I have shown that $y_{1}=e^{-x^2/4} $ is a solution of the ODE.

Comment: Can you please put your steps? The answer is hidden in the steps, and you do not need to find the solution, but actually analyse the exact differential.

Comment: I use the method of undetermined coefficients. Simply let y = exp(ax^2)